# DeWalt 20V cordless circular saw stops after 10 seconds

Tags: circular-saw

I have a brand new DeWalt 20V cordless circular saw.  I need to make very long (14-feet) cuts on a lot of boards.  The problem is that the saw stops cutting after about 10 seconds.
At first I thought the batteries were dead and made two 10-second cuts (I have two batteries) then recharged for hours, then make another set of two 10-second cuts.  But I tested the batteries on my drill and they work fine. I discovered that if I take the battery out of the saw and put it back in, it will cut for another 10 seconds.  The blade is new and is the proper depth.  What is going on?  Should I return this for a corded saw?

Comment: Faulty saw. Return and get a replacement. Personally, I prefer a corded saw over a battery one 9/10 times.

Comment: I would exchange that particular saw for another (of course how many other compatible tools one had impacts an exchange vs a different line). My (different brand) saw will last many feet of cuts on one battery.

Comment: Only thing I can imagine is that the saw is getting an "overheated" message. Will the saw run for over 10 s if it is not in wood? I cannot believe this would be normal behavior for a properly functioning saw, unless you are pushing it and the saw is being overloaded.

Comment: Seems like that saw is defective.  Would return at least.  Unless you need to use batteries, cutting wood should be on corded saws when possible.

Comment: What size is the battery? I can imagine the 1.5Ah might be overheating. This might be exacerbated by a deep cut with a blade that's not designed for ripping. Maybe a corded saw or one of Dewalt's better saws (I have a DCS577, and I don't even bother traveling with my corded saw anymore) are options. Having said all that, Dewalt will take anything back for any reason inside 90 days.

Comment: I think you are pushing the saw too hard, making it jam and overheat.